# Role based access for individual micro-services ( Zuul & Oauth 2.0)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2, netflix-zuul

I am developing multiple services with Spring Boot 2. I am using zuul for API gateway. 
I have security implemented only for the API gateway(Zuul).  I use OAuth 2.0. 
The problem I have right now is, I need to implement role-based access. Since the security and access control is implemented only at API Gateway I am not able to achieve the role based access in individual micro-services. If I need to enable in all micro-services, I lose the purpose of API gateway as well. 
What is the best way to achieve role based access in individual microservices(Spring Boot) while I have Zuul implemented as API Gateway?

Comment: Have you found any solution ?